# Increment a matrix based on another matrix of indices

Tags: r, performance, matrix, indices

I have a matrix:

```
a <- matrix(0,nrow=26,ncol=26)
tags <- sample(letters)
colnames(a) <- tags
rownames(a) <- tags
```

and another matrix:

```
b <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2,1,2,3,5,5,5),nrow=5,ncol=2)
```

I want to increment all cells in `a` whose indices are specified in each row of `b`

This would induce the following changes:

```
a[b[1,1],b[1,2]] <- a[b[1,1],b[1,2]] +1
a[b[2,1],b[2,2]] <- a[b[2,1],b[2,2]] +1
...
```

I am looking for an efficient solution preferably one that doesn't involve loops

Comment: Btw, if you're -indeed- using sparse matrices, consider, also, something like `Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = b[, 1], j = b[, 2], x = 1L, dims = c(26, 26), dimnames = list(tags, tags))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
library(dplyr)
countB <- data.frame(b) %>% group_by(X1, X2) %>% summarise(Count = n())
a[as.matrix(countB[-3])] <- countB[[3]]
```

Comment: this doesn't increment more than once for repeated indices. Notice how matrix b contains indices (1,2) three times I expect a[1,2] to be 3 but instead it is 1

Comment: I think it may be more convenient if you aggregate the data before assigning them? Like count the occurrences of the same indices.

Comment: As a side note, matrix b is filled by column so you don't really have (1,2) for three times but (1,5) twice. if you want to fill it by row you can specify the `byrow` parameter to be true.

Comment: you are right, I omitted the byrow= true parameter in my example

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
v1 <- ave(seq_len(nrow(b)), b[,1], b[,2], FUN = length)
i1 <- !duplicated(b)

a[b[i1,]] <- v1[i1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `count` function from `dplyr`:

```
library(plyr)
cnt <- as.matrix(count(b,c(1,2)))
     # x.1 x.2 freq
# [1,]   1   2    1
# [2,]   1   5    2
# [3,]   2   3    1
# [4,]   2   5    1

a[cnt[,1:2]] <- cnt[,3]
```

Or compute the count using base R:

```
cnt <- as.data.frame(as.table(table(as.data.frame(b))))

  # V1 V2 Freq
# 1  1  2    1
# 2  2  2    0
# 3  1  3    0
# 4  2  3    1
# 5  1  5    2
# 6  2  5    1
```